# Create multipe charts using filtered data from a table

Tags: reportbuilder3.0

I'm developing a report on Report Builder 3.0 that should look like following image.

[image: Report - Runtime]

Each pie chart should receive the value of the properties "Approved" and "Reproved" for a specific date and machine.

Is it possible to filter these properties on each Date/Machine group? The DataSet may include other properties that will be shown on the Property/Value table, but will not be included on the chart

At this moment I have the following model for the report

[image: Report - Design]

I´ve tryed to use the lookup function, but, as expected, it returns all the values on the DataSet. Is it possible to narrow the search scope?

Below is the DataSet that I'm using for the test:

```
|Machine|Machine_ID|Date|Property|Value|
|--------|---|----------------------|--------|---|
|Machine5|A|2017-02-12 20:00:00.000|Total|200|
|Machine5|A|2017-02-12 20:00:00.000|Approved|150|
|Machine5|A|2017-02-12 20:00:00.000|Reproved|50|
|Machine2|B|2017-02-12 20:00:00.000|Total|0|
|Machine2|B|2017-02-12 20:00:00.000|Approved|0|
|Machine2|B|2017-02-12 20:00:00.000|Reproved|0|
|Machine1|C|2017-02-12 20:00:00.000|Total|100|
|Machine1|C|2017-02-12 20:00:00.000|Approved|80|
|Machine1|C|2017-02-12 20:00:00.000|Reproved|20|
|Machine1|C|2017-02-13 20:00:00.000|Total|300|
|Machine1|C|2017-02-13 20:00:00.000|Approved|200|
|Machine1|C|2017-02-13 20:00:00.000|Reproved|100|
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could someone help me with the table format? This is my first question on stackoverflow and I'm still learning how to format the questions.

Comment: I fixed your table format up a bit; after it's reviewed and approved, it should look a bit better.

Comment: Thank you @SeanWerkema for the table format up and also for including images on the question body.

Comment: Very welcome. I'm sorry I can't answer it, but I can at least make the question pretty for someone who can :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be doable with row groups in a list.

- Insert a list
- Add a parent row group to group on DATE.
- Group your details region on MachineID
- Insert a tablix into the detail region rectangle
- Insert a graph next to it
- Insert a column next to the detail region (to the left) to get the MachineID column

It should look like this..
[image: Layout]

This shows the two row groups, and the detail region with the tablix and the graph.